# How to force jQuery mobile to apply styling after ajax request and page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to force jQuery Mobile to apply styling to contents  loaded in after an ajax call.

I am unable to post link to my json file for privacy and security reasons but I posted the code below.

What I am trying to do now is that  after I do some stuff with the json files, I then load the result into the .ui.content. It works just fine but the styling do not apply.

I am new to JQuerymobile and I read I would use something like .trigger('create') and I have tried to but I do not know what is happening and it is still not styling it or maybe I am not doing it the right way..

Here is the code I use.

Thanks.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Our Video Download</title>
    
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
    </style>
 
<style>
 a{
  text-decoration:none;
  
  }
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="content" data-role="page">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Video Download</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 <div id="display"> Display Place </div>
<input id="studio" type="button" value="Studio" onclick="processit('linktostudio.json')"/> 

<input id="family" type="button" value="Family" onclick="processit('linktofamily.json')"/> 
<input id="teenagers" type="button" value="Teenagers" onclick="processit('linktoteenager.json')"/> 


 


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
 
 <!-- File size conversion feature -->
function humanFileSize(bytes, si) {
 var thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if(Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
        return bytes + ' B';
    }
    var units = si
        ? ['kB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB']
        : ['KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];
    var u = -1;
    do {
        bytes /= thresh;
        ++u;
    } while(Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
    return bytes.toFixed(1)+' '+units[u];
}
// File conversion function ends here 
html = "";


            function processit(url){

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

           category_and_description = '<h1> JW Video ::' + json.category.name + "</h1> <br />" + json.category.description;
       html += category_and_description;
        categoryname = json.category.name;
       $.each(json.category.subcategories, function() {
         
         
            subcategoryname =  this.name;
            category_and_subcategory = '<h2> ' + categoryname + "->" + subcategoryname + '</h2>';
             html += category_and_subcategory;
             
             $.each(this.media, function(){
             
             //Individual video title
              videotitle = this.title;
              videoduration = this.durationFormattedMinSec;
              vid_title = '<div data-role=\"collapsible\" data-collapsed-icon=\"carat-d\" data-expanded-icon=\"carat-u\" data-content-theme=\"a\"  data-default="true" data-inset=\"true\"> <h4>' + videotitle + '</h4 </div>';
              vid_duration = '<strong>' + this.durationFormattedMinSec + '</strong>';
                 html += vid_title;
             //$.each(this.)
              // alert(videotitle + "\n" + videoduration);
                $.each(this.files, function(k, v){
                      eachlink = '<a href=' + v.progressiveDownloadURL + ' ' + ' data-role="button"  data-enhance="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-inline="true" data-mini=false>' +  v.label  + "->" + humanFileSize(v.filesize,true) + '</a>';
                 html += eachlink;
                 //$('.ui-content').trigger("create");
                 $('.ui-content').html(html);
                 
                })
                

              
             })
             
             
             
             
                         

             });

      
      
                    }
     
     
                });
    

     };

    </script> 
</div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>

</div>




        
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put in the callback of your ajax call

Comment: How do I get that done?

Comment: try to style the elements at the end of your success function

Comment: I do the styling before loading the content into the page.

Comment: we can put the required styles under one class name .mapStyles { } then on success callback, just apply this class to content container or body.